# Navigation Drawer icon not showing when opening menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Below code is `Navigation Drawer` with `toolbar` in my app:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.empty, R.string.empty) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    drawerToggle.syncState();


   @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
       drawerToggle.syncState();
   }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMenu"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**The menu can show correctly, but when menu is opening, the menu icon is disappear** like below image:

[image]

And here is normal state:

[image]

Is there any idea?

Comment: If i understand correctly.There is nothing wrong.ListView is just overlapping the menu icon.Menu icon is not disappear.It is just at left corner,below ListView.

Comment: Yes as @Cbibejs mentions that using `Drawerlayout` you can't expect the content to be moved while drawer is open. if you put your `ListView` below `Toolbar` you will see that the indicator stays at the same position.

Comment: @Android-Developer both of you are right. Moving Listview to below toolbar then menu icon can show correctly. But my app expect the full height menu look like this. I wonder  can Navigation Drawer handle this case or I need to use 3rd party lib like https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu ?

Comment: Yes you can achieve that using `SlidingMenu` not with `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for me :

```
  drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle

  drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // To display hamburger icon in toolbar
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
```

You need to put `drawerToggle.syncState();` inside `Runnable()` and only add `drawerToggle.syncState();` once in code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. **The icon is showing correctly when menu is closed** . But when I open menu, icon is gone.

Comment: You need to put your listview inside a fragment and after that you need to set `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(your Fragment View);`

Comment: Why you are setting `drawerToggle.syncState();` twice in your code?

Comment: It's just my mistake. I removed duplicate `syncState()` calling.  For `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(fragment)`, I tried it and didn't work too. It just opens menu programmatically, while I need to listen users's action when they click on menu icon

Comment: i have little bit different issue..i am following this tutorial..http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/...and trying to get hamburger icon which mentioned in question..can you help me with this